# Remove an object if it overlaps another object libgdx

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, collision, destroy

I'm new at libgdx and Android game development. so I need your help.
I have code that detects collisions. I use the rectangle method.
If objectA overlaps objectB then I want that objectA get destroyed.

this is my code for now:

```
if (objectA.getBounds().overlaps(objectB.getBounds())) {
        System.out.println("Collsion Detected!");
        }
```

System.out.println works fine.
But i don't know how i can "delete" objectA if it overlaps.

Thanks

Comment: We also don't know it, as long as you don't describe what exactly you mean by "delete". Usually you have some kind of collection of things in your game which you update in every frame and render in every frame. If you remove objectA from that, it's gone for example.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove object, if it is only image (`Texture`/`Sprite` etc) you should just don't `draw` it in `render()` method. Example:

```
Sprite objectIwantToRemove= new Sprite();
// init your sprite here.....

if (objectA.getBounds().overlaps(objectB.getBounds())) {
    objectIwantToRemove=null; //here i mark it as null, you can remove it from your ArrayList or anything else. Depends how you keeps it.
    }

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
  if(objectIwantToRemove!=null){
    spriteBatch.begin();
    objectIwantToRemove.draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.end();
  }
}
```

P.S It is very basic example, just in order to let you know how to remove images. If you use Box2D it is other story...

Comment: How would you remove it from your array list?

Comment: From ArrayList as any other object: listName.remove(object);

Comment: Never mind, I fixed the issue by using the group.removeValue() method.